# The name of the project must be... issue

Tags: java, eclipse

What causes something like the following to occur?

[image: The name of the new project must be 'tester' (Tester typed in)]

The name is clearly typed in as Tester; I don't know why Eclipse thinks it's an error and must be 'tester'.  It doesn't have an issue with other projects starting with uppercase letters.  There are no projects in the current workspace I am using.  It's not against convention, either (that I know of).  My only idea is that there's such a strong convention to name projects 'tester' when they are created with that name that Eclipse decided to make it an error if it wasn't exactly 'tester'.

Comment: I don't know why you're having this problem. Eclipse (Juno, release 1), works fine with this project title and without complaint.

Comment: Might this be a Windows-specific issue?  Something to do with the file system being case insensitive?

Comment: Are you creating a brand new project or importing an existing one?

Comment: Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819.  Windows 7, x64 system, SP1 (upgraded from Vista).  I am creating a brand new project.

Comment: Works with Kepler under Windows 8. I wonder why the JRE selection area is grayed out too ... It's not the case on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you have (previously?) renamed the project outside of Eclipse; see this bug report.

- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XTENLANG-1386

(The bug report is unclear, and it looks like the resolution of "Fixed" does not match what actually happened.  But this might explain what is happening to you.)

Comment: I didn't rename the project outside of Eclipse; thanks for trying.

Comment: Well, based on the evidence, it must be something like that.  For some reason, Eclipse thinks that there was previously a project called "tester", and that you should be using the same name as before.